# Could not select LastLogin field from volusion store generic customers table

Tags: php, volusion

I have a PHP application which connects to a Volusion store and exports customers details using query string. But I can't select the `LastLogin` field from customers table, it does not show in the XML data. My query string is as follows:

```
$url="http://www.domain.com/net/WebService.aspx? Login=jusername&EncryptedPassword=7602B3272D929D17B5138382F2AE4F4C6102A12AEB1F476293C16A5F731949B6&EDI_Name=Generic\Customers&SELECT_Columns=CustomerID,LastLogin";
```

When I run the query I get results with fields `CustomerID` and `EmailAddress` instead of `CustomerID` and `lastLogin`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve the LastLogin data for specific customer ID using this method through the Volusion API.

If you want to retrieve all of the LastLogin data for all customers at the same time you will have to run a saved SQL query via the API. This SQL query would be stored in your generic folder along with the required XSD file.

You would then run it like a API call but instead call the file.

The text in the SQL file would be something like

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.LastLogin FROM Customers WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY Customers.CustomerID
```

Assuming file name is lastlogin.sql, you would call it like so but without the sql extension.

```
...&EDI_Name=Generic\lastlogin
```

EDIT:

For specific customer you would use the following.

```
...&EDI_Name=Generic\Customers&SELECT_Columns=CustomerID,LastLogin&WHERE_Column=CustomerID&WHERE_Value=146
```

Comment: i tried to select lastlogin field using the query, url/WebService.aspx?Login=username&EncryptedPassword=password&EDI_Name=Generic\Customers&SELECT_Columns=CustomerID,CompanyName,LastLogin&WHERE_Column=CustomerID&WHERE_Value=146, but its not work.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? If the LastLogin field is empty then it will not return any data. Make sure the account you are using to run the API request has sufficient privileges to access the information.

Comment: i have superadmin privileges .but LastLogin field is not shown in result set

Comment: Then the id you are trying is probably an anonymous customer therefore they have never logged in. Try a customer which is not anonymous or an admin customer ID.

Comment: Thank you! I've been using Volusion for 12 years and never knew this was a thing. I never saw it in documentation or anything.