# How to write join query in Volusion API

Tags: php, mysql, api, volusion

I have a PHP application which connects to *Volusion* store and exports data using query string, and the query string in API like following

```php
$url="http://www.domain.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=jusername&EncryptedPassword=7602B3272D929D17B5138382F2AE4F4C6102A12AEB1F476293C16A5F731949B6&EDI_Name=Generic\Customers&SELECT_Columns=CustomerID,LastLogin";
```

Now I want to fetch data from multiple tables and  my query is like

```sql
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Customers.CompanyName, Customers.EmailAddress, Login_History.LastModified  FROM Customers JOIN Login_History ON (Login_History.CustomerID=Customers.Customerid)
```

Does anyone know how to write `JOIN` query in Volusion API connection URL?

Comment: you cannot run an SQL call of this nature directly through the Volusion API. You can however run a SQL call via a saved text file. I explained this to your here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936437/could-not-select-lastlogin-field-from-volusion-store-generic-customers-table/29056295#29056295

Comment: i tried that but not working . I contacted volusion support they  said " The saved exports you can manually export only through the saved exports tab. Unfortunately we do not have a built in method of exporting them via the API".

Comment: Sadly, your mistake was to contact V support for assistance. Most of them support staff don't know there own product. It is possible to do what I said.

Answer (score 4):

Using notepad or similar editor copy and paste the following into it and save it as loginhistory.sql or whatever you want but it must have an .sql extension.

```
 SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Customers.CompanyName, Customers.EmailAddress, Login_History.LastModified  FROM Customers JOIN Login_History ON (Login_History.CustomerID=Customers.Customerid)
```

This will work but certainly not correctly formatted. I'll leave it to you on writing a XSD file. Copy the following to a editor like Notepad and save it with the same name as above but with a .xsd extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
</xs:schema>
```

FTP the two files above to your Generic folder.

```
/v/vspfiles/schema/Generic/
```

You can now run the SQL query via the API using the URL

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=username&EncryptedPassword=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&EDI_Name=Generic\loginhistory
```

Be sure to edit in your specific API credentials in the URL.

Comment: thanks. what a crock of nonsense this api is. xml schemas manually uploaded through ftp? really volusion? who decided this?