# Volusion API - How to retrieve orders by date

Tags: volusion

I am making a call to the volusion api generic order export and I want to be able to only get orders for a single day however the date it is being compared to is a full timestamp stored in the volusion database so you'd have to have the entire timestamp and not just d/mm/yyyy. Seems like it is impossible to pull orders by date via the api. If anyone has experience with the generic orders export with the Volusion api your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly via the Volusion API as you have already stated.

You can however run a stored SQL query. The method to do this is explained here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29134928/357034

You just have to create your specific SQL query which returns the data you require.

Comment: Yeah - no we need to call the API to get the information.

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote in the other thread. It does exactly what you  require.

Comment: That's awesome to hear! Trying it now. I am having an issue connecting via ftp through a ftp tool so that I upload my files. Any ideas? I am using the same un and pw that we connect to the service api with. It says connected but then times out waiting for welcome message.

Comment: OK I figured out how to get into the ftp account - I needed the my volusion account details to get in and figure out what the ftp credentials are. Issue I am having now is that it says I am missing the xsd file. "Could not find file &#39;D:\Domains\ecommerce\_v_6_0_net\_v_6_5_net\net\schema\Generic\Last30DaysOrders.xsd&#39;." - however I did place it in the generic folder. Hrmmm. Looking into this now.

Comment: So I keep getting the error: Could not find file &#39;D:\Domains\ecommerce\_v_6_0_net\_v_6_5_net\net\schema\Generic\Test.xsd&#39;. I copy an xsd file that is already in there and rename it to just try to test and I keep getting this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it to work. Awesome work around to a not so great api. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score -2):

For other who might come along later... I had the same error and I believe I solved the problem by switching the user to SuperAdmin rights.