# How to retrieve Orders from Volusion using his API

Tags: c#, api, e-commerce, webrequest

I have a c# application which connects to Volusion store, I need to get all Orders. I'm trying this

http://mywebsite/net/WebService.aspx?Login="myuser"&EncryptedPassword="mypassword"&EDI_Name=Generic\Orders&SELECT_Columns=*WHERE_Column=o.OrderStatus&WHERE_Value=Processing

and I getting this in response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xmldata />
```

I am using Postman to do this. I have an Order already crated in my store in processing status. What I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try removing some of your conditions inside Where's to see if anything comes back then, table maybe empty? For writing more complex queries check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29134928/3254405

Comment: you mean do this http://mywebsite/net/WebService.aspx?Login="myuser"&EncryptedPassword="mypassword"&EDI_Name=Generic\Orders&SELECT_Columns=*

Comment: yes try that to get something working, or this \Orders&SELECT_Columns=OrderStatus

Comment: I try that already too and nothing , is frustrating

Comment: Instead of using c# app can you get anything back in the browser directly..

Comment: I'm getting this:  This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<xmldata/>

Comment: The only thing I can suggest (apart from trying the link I've sent earlier) is test with this program because you need to post (not get), which you can't do in a browser.. https://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the API user credentials that you are using have the proper level of access or nothing will be returned. I would recommend setting up a separate API account for this specific function not used for general administration. This way you will not have to be concerned about updating the user password and thus you will not have a changing Encrypted Password in turn.

Comment: thank you , the API user credentials are fine, I talk with Volusion the tell me that I have to reset the API, and it work. Volusion's issues, nothing else.